# Check for comma delimited string with regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to parse a set of commands and test with a regular expression for example:

```
PLACE 1,2,EAST
MOVE
MOVE
LEFT
MOVE
REPORT
```

How can I test the format `1,2,EAST` is correct?

Just want to check that first two terms are numbers, between [0-5] AND that the last term is either `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, `WEST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex constraints translate to

```
[0-5],[0-5],(?:EAST|WEST|NORTH|SOUTH)
```